# inner product and parallelogram equation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

[image]

So I know that if ∥⃗v∥ is associated to an inner product •, then it satisfies the parallelogram equality:

∥⃗u + ⃗v∥^2 + ∥⃗u − ⃗v∥^2 = 2(∥⃗u∥^2 + ∥⃗v∥^2)

for all ⃗u and ⃗v.

I also know that I need to find two vectors for which the parallelogram
equality fails.

For example I take  ⃗u = ⃗e1 and ⃗v = ⃗e2.

After this step I am not really sure what to do.

Comment: Theres a lot of boxes here, rather than math. please typeset it with mathjax.

Comment: @Batman I have started learning it two days ago. I am still not sure how to use it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u = (1,0)$ and $v = (0,1)$, we have $2(\|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2) = 4$ but $\|u + v\|^2 + \|u - v\|^2 = 8$. Therefore the parallelogram law does not hold.